# Can linux boot from a disk that has no partition table?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I have a linux system on a disk that seems to have no partition table.

gparted shows Partition table: none

df shows / mounted from /dev/sdb1

Update:  When I boot from another disk, then I see that /dev/sdb has a gpt partition table, and I can see the free space.  So the question is why does gparted on the new system not see the partition table?

How is it possible to have a filesystem on a disk that has no partition table?

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on this disk, after deleting all partitions with gparted.  In the Ubuntu installer, I selected the empty disk (330 GB) and created a 30 GB root partition.  The newly installed system runs happily, but I cannot create more partitions on that disk.  I'm perplexed.  How can I access the free space on the disk?  Should I repartition the disk myself and run the installer again?  Is my disk defective?

Comment: Putting a filesystem on a bare drive is not a problem. Crafting or configuring a bootloader to boot off such a drive is a bit trickier.

Comment: What do other tools say? `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`, `gdisk -l /dev/sdb`, `parted`, …

Comment: I added 2 more partitions with gparted (booted from another disk).  fdisk, gdisk and parted can see the partition table and all 3 partitions.  gparted (booted from the disk in question) sees no partition table and sees the whole disk as a "zfs" partition (the disk did have a zfs partition before).

Answer (score 2):

Linux and BSD can put a filesystem on a disk with no partition table.

It's recommended for ZFS pools : You give up the ability to ID your filesystem by partition type, which can make some types of auto-detection more difficult, especially with other OS.

Pools can also be constructed using partitions rather than whole disks. Putting ZFS in a separate partition allows the same disk to have other partitions for other purposes.

It seems like the disk was not fully formatted and still contains ZFS,
at least on the first partition.
Other partitions can contain bootcode and file systems needed for booting
if required,

For more information see
[zpool Administration](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/zfs-zpool.html).